# Rebind service in runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm writing an app which reads messages from rabbitmq. A message contains a user's name and a correlation ID. There is a message handler which performs some calculations based on the message's payload and writes logs as well. A log entry must contain a user's name and a correlation ID from the message.

So, for each message, a new instance of MessageProcessor is created and a new instance of ExecutionContext should be created as well.

I'm using `Microsoft.DependencyInjection` which comes with .net core and I can't achieve the desired behaviour.

I tried to use `Replace` method but it did not work.

MessageProcessor.cs

```cs
internal sealed class MessageProcessor
{
    public MessageProcessor(ILogger logger) 
    {
    }

    public async Task Process(Message message)
    {
        // do something useful
        this.logger.WriteInfo("Message has been processed");
    }

}
```

Logger.cs

```cs
internal sealed class Logger
{
    public Logger(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        //context contains UserName and CorrelationID
    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to rebind `ExecutionContext` for each message? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend creating a new instance of MessageProcessor with every arrived message. It is better to use the one instance of the processor and just delegate messages:

```
//register your processor in DI container
services.AddSingleton<MessageProcessor>();
```

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(Model);
consumer.Received += OnMessageReceived;

Model.BasicConsume(
  queue: queueName,
  autoAck: true,
  consumer: consumer);

//...

private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
  var message = e.Body; //here's your message in bytes

  //deserialize into your model
  IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(obj.Body))
  {
    myMessage = (Message) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
  }

  //...
}
```

RabbitMQ operates with bytes, not with JSON/XML/...
Can you post your code of Model class and how the connection to Rabbit looks like?